# Outlook 2007 hangs when accessing address book in message composer

Tags: outlook-2007, contacts

I've had 2 machines this week to suffer this problem.  When creating a new message, replying to a message, forwarding, etc. - anything that uses the message composition/editor window - and the user attempts to use the address book via the "To:" or "CC:" or address book buttons, the contact list fails to appear and Outlook hangs.  Neither of the windows will take focus, and right-clicking the Windows taskbar buttons has no effect.  The app must then be shut down with Task Manager.

The address book will show up just fine when using the button in the main Outlook window.  The contacts list appears as expected when viewing from the main Outlook window.

The first problem machine started working after running a repair on the Office installation.  That didn't work on the second machine (several attempts).  I tested a new profile, but the problem also existed in the new profile.  I used the PST repair tool on outlook.pst, but that also failed to solve the problem.  I moved the contacts to a different folder, but the problem persisted.  And just this morning, I uninstalled and re-installed Outlook, but the problem is still there.

Any ideas what I'm missing here?  Or other troubleshooting suggestions?

Comment: Update: Starting Outlook in safe mode allows the address book to work correctly.  Does this help narrow down the possibilities?

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same problem.

In my case, it works 60% of the time, the 40% crashes. I think when it works one time, it works the rest of the time that Outlook is open. To test, I had to open-try-close, and repeat.

I'm on a brand new Exchange server and i'm not sure if it's the server or the clients.

Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I didn't get a notification of your post.  Yes, this was fixed a few months ago, but I can't find my documentation - I know I typed it up or scribbled it somewhere.  As I recall, the user ended up having a problem in some other Office app and repairing that problem also fixed the address book.  I want to say that it had something to do with using addresses in Word, but this user has so many ridiculous problems that I could be mingling them together in memory.  I'm sorry I can't provide anything useful.  We do not use an Exchange server, though.